# Find the number of integers between $1$ and $10000$ with at least one $8$ and at least one $9$ as digits

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of integers between $1$ and $10000$ with at least one $8$ and at least one $9$ as digits.

---

There are no $1$-digit such numbers.

Two digit numbers are $89$, $98$.

Three digit numbers are $989,899,998,988,889,898,999,888$, $89$_ ($8$ nos.), $98$_ ($8$ nos.), _$98$ ($7$ nos.), _$89$(nos.).

I cannot count the $4$-digit such numbers using this method.

Is there any better method to calculate the answer.The answer is $974$.

Comment: I don't know any type of metheds .I simply use counting while answering these type of problem.But it I so complex to count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's count the number of positive integers less than $10000$ in which the digit $8$ or the digit $9$ does not appear.

Since both $0$ and $10000$ contain neither an $8$ nor a $9$, the number of positive integers less than or equal $10000$ in which the digit $8$ or the digit $9$ does not appear is equal to the number of nonnegative integers less than $10000$ in which the digit $8$ or the digit $9$ does not appear.

A nonnegative integer less than $10000$ can be treated as a four-digit decimal sequence by appending leading zeros to a number with fewer than four digits.  For instance, we treat the number $74$ as the sequence $0074$.

The number of nonnegative integers less than $10000$ in which the digit $8$ does not appear is $9^4$ since we can fill the thousands place, hundreds place, tens place, and units place with any digit other than $8$.  By symmetry, there are also $9^4$ positive integers less than $10000$ in which the digit $9$ does not appear.  However, we have counted numbers in which neither the digit $8$ nor the digit $9$ appears twice.  There are $8^4$ such numbers.  Hence, there are 
$$2 \cdot 9^4 - 8^4$$
positive integers less than or equal to $10000$ in which the digit $8$ or the digit $9$ does not appear.  Therefore, there are 
$$10000 - 2 \cdot 9^4 + 8^4 = 974$$
positive integers less than $10000$ in which at least one $8$ and at least one $9$ appear.

Answer (score 4):

The number $abcd$ (where $a$ can be $0$) has one or several 8's.

- If the most leftward $8$ is $a$, you juste have to count the number of three-digits number $bcd$ with at least one $9$: $100+90+81=271$
- If the most leftward $8$ is $b$, then you have $100$ numbers with $a=9$, and $8$ times (the number of two digit numbers $cd$ with at least one $9$) other solutions : $100+8*19=252$
- If the most leftward $8$ is $c$, then you have $90$ numbers with $a=9$, $80$ numbers with $a\neq 9$ and $b=9$ and $64$ numbers with $a,b\neq 9$ and $d=9$ : $90+80+64=234$
- If the most leftward $8$ is $d$, you juste have to count the number of three-digits number $abc$ with at least one $9$ and no $8$: $81+72+64=217$

Finally, $271+252+234+217=974$.

Comment: Python agrees with you